# list index out of range in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, fft

I need to create a program in python using fourier transform. It says: list index out of range,and I don;t understand why.  The error is at these lines:

```
Feven = fft([x[i] for i in xrange(0, n, 2)],n/2)
Fodd = fft([x[i] for i in xrange(1, n, 2)],n/2)
```

Comment: Test `len(x) >= n` beforehand. If `False`, you have a problem with `n` too big. Otherwise if `n == len(x)`, you can replace the list comprehensions with `x[::2]` and `x[1::2]` respectively.

Comment: The 1st step here is to refactor the list comp OUT of the call, to make sure what actually raises the exception ("fft" can do, too).

Comment: @pyroscope If that were the case, the stack trace would show more calls below this one.

Comment: Looping by index is also a really terrible idea. What are you actually trying to get, as there is probably a better way to do it, (as eumiro points out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried separating the the list compilation from function call to find out the location the exception is thrown?

```
# assuming n <= len(x)
even = [x[i] for i in xrange(0, n, 2)]
Feven = fft(even,n/2)
```

You could also use slicing to get every second element in list:

```
even = x[::2]
odd = x[1::2]
```